# JSX element type does not have a construct or call signature

Tags: reactjs, typescript, spfx

I am trying to get the  working in my SPFX application and I am sure I am not getting the class correct

I have tried my code in JS and ran it with npm install and it works fine, but when I try and do it in TS with spfx I get this error:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';



 export const Checkbox = ({ type = 'checkbox', checked = false, onChange, id }) => {

return <input id={id} type={type} checked={checked} onChange={onChange} />;
};

Checkbox.propTypes = {
type: PropTypes.string,
name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
checked: PropTypes.bool,
onChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

and I call it with :

```
return (
 <label style={{display: 'block'}} key={item.id}>
                            <Checkbox
                                style={{display: 'block'}}
                                checked={checked}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                id={item.id}
                                statement={item.statement}
                            />
                            {item.statement}
                        </label>
```

My exact error is :error TS2604: JSX element type 'Checkbox' does not have any construct or call signatures.

Any ideas clever folks ?

Comment: Can you also post how do you import your Checkbox component?

Comment: I get your error if I use `import Checkbox = require("./Checkbox");` use `import { Checkbox } from "./Checkbox";` instead.

Comment: Hi guys, yes this my import :  import * as Checkbox from './Checkbox';

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't use a default export you need to either specify what component you are importing from the module:

```
import { Checkbox } from './Checkbox
```

Or you can use a default export and import it using the apropriate syntax

```
const Checkbox = /* ... */
export default Checkbox;

import Checkbox from './Checkbox
```

Comment: great but I now get this error :  error TS2339: Property 'style' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { type?: string; checked?: boolean; onChange: any; id: any; }'. and thats on the <checkbox> item

Comment: @Jason_Hough ok, but that is a different issue. Your Checkbox component is not defined to take in a style or statement props ..

Comment: ok thank you, but why does it work when I compile it all in JS ? and the style and the statement props doesn't error ?